# SQL - matching 3 from 5 criterias

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible with sql (postgres) to make a query which searches for entries which match any 3 criterias of 5 possible? I am not getting anywhere at the moment and i am stuck.
Plz, help out.

Comment: What do you mean with "criteria" ? You intend three different column or three different column's values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a verbose, yet straight-forward solution to this problem:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (CASE t.val WHEN :criteria1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE t.val WHEN :criteria2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE t.val WHEN :criteria3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE t.val WHEN :criteria4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE t.val WHEN :criteria5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3
```

You could also do tricks with semi-joining an unnested array:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[:c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5]) u(val)
  WHERE u.val = t.val
) >= 3
```

Or by semi-joining a `VALUES(...)` expression

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2), (2), (2)) u(val)
  WHERE u.val = t.val
) >= 3
```

Here's a working example, which I've put on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/585):

```
WITH t(val) AS (
  VALUES (1), (2), (4), (6)
)
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2), (2), (2)) u(val)
  WHERE u.val = t.val
) >= 3
```

The above will return 2, as it is the only record that matches at least three criteria among `(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)`

Comment: You are both right, and both are good. Why couldnt I think about that. I accept the one who posted earlier. Sry.

Comment: The "generation" of the dummy data can be written in a more compact way using `with t(val) as ( values (1),(2),(4),(6) )`. I personally think it's more readable than the union all syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're right, thanks. I forgot that Postgres supported this syntax as well...

Comment: Why do an `unnest(ARRAY...)` Wouldn't a `FROM (VALUES (..), (..)) u (val)` be nicer ?

Comment: @greg: Yes of course. It would work just the same. The advantage of an array expression is the fact that the array could be bound as a single variable, if the statement was executed from Java, for instance

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE IF(crit1, 1,0)
+ IF(crit2, 1,0)
+ IF(crit3, 1,0)
+ IF(crit4, 1,0)
+ IF(crit5, 1,0) >= 3
```

[Edit] As per below comment this is not valid postgres. This is how it would be done in MySQL, I just assumed it's standard... The CASE statement is more relevant to the original question.

Comment: That is not a valid PostgreSQL statement.